# Link List Implementation. Hacker Rank Video

Tags: linked-list

I am learning DS and came across a short video tutorial of Hacker Rank on Linked List.

It is pretty much self explanatory, but I am not able to understand one point where she said "**If we pre-append then we will have little bit of issue**". Here she basically tells that **move append code outside in another class**.
I am trying to understand and visualise what actually she meant and what could be the potential issue if we keep it in Node class itself. She mentioned but I am not able to grasp that concept.

Here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njTh_OwMljA&t=186s
Time: ***3:01***.

Could someone elaborate it bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular problem arises when you are trying to pre-append (append values at the start).

Multiples objects are created of the node class. Say your list is like this, `1->2->3->4->5` with each number being one node.

Now you want to do normal append (at the end), you call `3.append()` . `current` points to `3`, you iterate till the last node and append it. No issues over here.

Now when you try to pre-append it, you are ideally changing the head of each nodes present in the list.

Say you want to pre append `0`. Your list should look like `0->1->2->3->4->5`. `0` being the actual head of linked list.

If you call the same way `3.pre_append()`, you would end up with something like

`1->2->3 X 0->3->4->5`, where you would be changing the head of the node from which you called the function and not the head of entire linked list which you meant to do.

So only that node will have its head changed and all other nodes won't know who head is or worse there might be multiple heads based on who calls pre_append.

In order to avoid this access to the head was limited and hence the pre_append method was shifted to another class where only one node can be referenced as the head.